# iOS SIGABRT on dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to get a UICollectionView working in my application and for some reason I keep getting a sigabrt. The error I am getting is

*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

I have googled around, and it seems like most of the time this is related to the neglecting to registerClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier, but I am doing this as required in the view did load method. My code is as follows:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [self.collectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell " forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: There should be another line to the error message explaining the specific problem. Try clicking Continue in the Xcode debugger until the app actually crashes; you may get more output in the debug console.

Comment: If you copied the code correctly then your cell identifiers don't match.

Comment: Haha, that was it. Typo in the cell identifiers! Thanks!

Comment: NEVER use hard-coded identifiers, if only to avoid mistakes like these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one cell identifier is "Cell" & another one is "Cell ". i.e. extra space after cell, remove it.