# How to get numeric value of an enum, or setting an enum with numeric value, in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have this piece of code to add new cell on a collection view. The delegate and datasource has been set properly. But the collection view cell did not show anything. Well, when I debug it, it shows that the cell is created, but the cell contains nothing other than a `UIView`, where I expect it should contains a `UIButton` with a `UIImageView` inside it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setImgGallery:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    [[self cvPictureGallery] registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new"];
    [[self cvPictureGallery] registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review"];

    // add 5 UIImage test to imgGallery.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        [[self imgGallery] addObject:[UIImage named:@"test.png"]];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return MIN ([[self imgGallery] count] + 1, 5);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath row] == [[self imgGallery] count]) { // show the camera icon
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
               - button
                 - camera icon
            */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

            UIImageView * imgCameraIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"]];
            [imgCameraIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            [imgCameraIcon setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

            UIButton * btnCamera = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [btnCamera addSubview:btnCamera];
            [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(openCameraTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imgCameraIcon setCenter:CGPointMake([btnCamera width] / 2, [btnCamera height] / 2)];

            [cell addSubview:btnCamera];
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new"];
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
               - button
                 - image selected
            */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

            UIImageView * imgSelected = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[self imgGallery] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
            [imgSelected setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [imgSelected setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
            [imgSelected setTag:1];

            UIButton * btnCamera = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [btnCamera addSubview:btnCamera];
            [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [imgSelected setCenter:CGPointMake([btnCamera width] / 2, [btnCamera height] / 2)];

            [cell addSubview:btnCamera];
            [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review"];
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

I have used the reference on these QA:

- [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866624/ios-sigabrt-on-dequeuereusablecellwithreuseidentifier) on `registerClass`.

EDIT: based on the accepted answer and discussion there, this is my updated code, which still doesn't show anything:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath row] == [[self imgGallery] count]) { // show the camera icon
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
               - button
                 - camera icon
            */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

            UIImageView * imgCameraIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"]];
            [imgCameraIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            [imgCameraIcon setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
            [imgCameraIcon setTag:1];

            UIButton * btnCamera = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [btnCamera addSubview:imgCameraIcon];
            [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(openCameraTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnCamera setTag:2];
            [imgCameraIcon setCenter:CGPointMake([btnCamera width] / 2, [btnCamera height] / 2)];

            [cell addSubview:btnCamera];
            [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new"];
        }

        UIImageView * imgCameraIcon = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
        [imgCameraIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"]];

        NSLog (@"Subview count:%lu", (unsigned long)[[cell subviews] count]);

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
               - button
                 - image selected
            */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

            UIImageView * imgSelected = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[self imgGallery] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
            [imgSelected setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [imgSelected setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
            [imgSelected setClipsToBounds:YES];
            [imgSelected setTag:1];

            UIButton * btnImage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
            [btnImage addSubview:imgSelected];
            [btnImage addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnImage setTag:2];
            [imgSelected setCenter:CGPointMake([btnImage width] / 2, [btnImage height] / 2)];

            [cell addSubview:btnImage];
        }

        UIImageView * imgSelected = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
        [imgSelected setImage:[[self imgGallery] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        NSLog (@"Subview count:%lu", (unsigned long)[[cell subviews] count]);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

The result of Subview count is always 1. Below, is the working one, but the subview count is increasing each time.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath row] == [[self imgGallery] count]) { // show the camera icon
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
               - button
                 - camera icon
            */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        }

        UIImageView * imgCameraIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"]];
        [imgCameraIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [imgCameraIcon setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        UIButton * btnCamera = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [btnCamera addSubview:imgCameraIcon];
        [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(openCameraTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imgCameraIcon setCenter:CGPointMake([btnCamera width] / 2, [btnCamera height] / 2)];

        [cell addSubview:btnCamera];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new"];

        NSLog (@"Subview count:%lu", (unsigned long)[[cell subviews] count]);

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
               - button
                 - image selected
            */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        }

        UIImageView * imgSelected = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[self imgGallery] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [imgSelected setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [imgSelected setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [imgSelected setClipsToBounds:YES];
        [imgSelected setTag:1];

        UIButton * btnImage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [btnImage addSubview:imgSelected];
        [btnImage addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imgSelected setCenter:CGPointMake([btnImage width] / 2, [btnImage height] / 2)];

        [cell addSubview:btnImage];
        [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review"];

        NSLog (@"Subview count:%lu", (unsigned long)[[cell subviews] count]);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: collectionview register class should be on top before you actually call dequeReusableCell?

Comment: @Joshua after I did the selected correct answer's solution, it results correctly. I guess you only need to register it once for the lifetime of that collectionView.

Comment: yup but reading your selected answer i think that it does not reuse the cell properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you write the wrong code to create cell. Please update your code like as below and see output

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath row] == [[self imgGallery] count]) { // show the camera icon
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
             - button
             - camera icon
             */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        }
        UIImageView * imgCameraIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"]];
        [imgCameraIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [imgCameraIcon setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        UIButton * btnCamera = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [btnCamera addSubview:btnCamera];
        [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(openCameraTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imgCameraIcon setCenter:CGPointMake([btnCamera width] / 2, [btnCamera height] / 2)];

        [cell addSubview:btnCamera];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"new"];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            /*
             cell
             - contentView
             - button
             - image selected
             */

            cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        }
        UIImageView * imgSelected = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[self imgGallery] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [imgSelected setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [imgSelected setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        [imgSelected setTag:1];

        UIButton * btnCamera = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [btnCamera addSubview:btnCamera];
        [btnCamera addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imgSelected setCenter:CGPointMake([btnCamera width] / 2, [btnCamera height] / 2)];

        [cell addSubview:btnCamera];
        [collectionView registerClass:[cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"review"];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh you're correct. I forgot I put everything inside the bracket. Thank you very much!

Comment: just curious, isn't it that if you show the cell again it will add the button again? this will not reuse the cell properly. it will just add the btnCamera over and over again eventually you'll notice it when you scroll too much and it becomes slow.

Comment: @Joshua yea you actually right. I added `NSLog (@"Subview count:%lu", (unsigned long)[[cell subviews] count]);` right before returning the cell, and it shows the subview counts increases each time I call `reloadData`. But if I put all inside the brackets, and outside the brackets I call them each using `viewWithTag:`, and then load the image there, I still don't see anything. The subview counts stays at 1. I updated the code to let you see my modified code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure the title of your question in anyway is related to your query but please replace the line:

```
[btnCamera addSubView:btnCamera]
```

with

```
[btnCamera addSubView:imgCameraIcon]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. That's a slip in my part. Thanks!